# Can Clojure Spec be used to constrain protocol argument and return types?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'd like to know if spec can be used to constrain argument and return types on a protocol similar to how [fdef](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_specing_functions) works for functions.

The best lead I've found so far is [a section called protocols in the api documentation](https://clojure.github.io/spec-alpha2/#clojure.spec-alpha2.protocols), but it comes with little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK protocols generate host interfaces, and since those don't support the "dependent type like" constraints you can express in spec, I think you can't do this (though it does sound like a very nice idea!).